# UINavigationBar and UIScrollView resizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview

I've UIViewController with navigation bar and scrollview within it.
When scrollview scrolls down I hide navigation bar and set bounds for scrollview to fit free space.

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [scrollView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 411)];
```

Height is 411 cos there is also UITabBarController.
But scrollview doesn't fit whole view. When I check it's frame it says that frame = (0 22; 320 411); How could I fix that?

I've tried to use setFrame function instead of setBounds. Also I dont need to resize it's content I need to change its frame.

Comment: i think after set Frame use this two line     [scrollView setNeedsLayout];
    [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you use `setFrame` and also `setContentSize` if needed here...

its may be happen because off its content size not manage after your scrollview bounds are changed...
hope this help you....
:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the frame of the scrollview.

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 411);
```

The bounds is a coordinate system in relation to the view and not its containing view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setFrame function.

```
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 411)];
```